# GIT/Bitbucket Structure, handling application variations

Tags: git, bitbucket

HI i would like to what is the best way to manage a codebase wherein it would consist of a baseline code , ex. cms then I need 3 versions under that ex. cmsbikes, cmsjewels, cmsdress which have a variety of unique stuff under then, but if I need a general patch it would automatically propagate on all branches

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to update your own code with patches of yours, I think you need a dependency manager. You will have to cut in peaces your project and then, include bit a bit each part in one big project. Then, you might be in position to manage updates installing them with the manager.

For example, npm is a dependency manager from where you can install different "framworks" to include in your project. In your case, I understood you want to use your own code, so you will need to create your own framework.

Comment: I am using zend framework 2 for my current project. I already have the base code. the problem is I am going to use it on 3 different websites, realesate, cars, computers, so there would differences for example the html forms, and also there are general features.

Comment: Ok, then you need to use well the MVC pattern to be able to make visual changes. Define the pattern correctly to be able to inherit from your current class.

Comment: thus that mean I just need to create 3 unique branches for them?